# Windows GPUView

Tags: windows-7

I am hitting low FPS on one of the application that I am working on. I found that GPUView can be used for debugging graphics performance issues. I have collected Merged.etl file for use case. This shows FPS chart for my application. I am trying to understand co-relation between this chart and GPU Hardware Queue and CPU Context Queue. Basically I want to know how this FPS chart has been derived? If there is any event that can trace this information I am thinking of adding real time tracing of this event so that I can display the FPS as widget while I run my application, something similar to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/09/26/etw-event-tracing-in-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The FPS chart is derived from the event "D3D9 - Present"(maybe other similar name for d3d10/11)
the "D3D9 - Present" event is produced when the D3D runtime calls into the user mode graphic driver's interface [Present](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The FPS chat in GPUview only consider the counter of Present called, but for some application, like windows media player, it will call Present twice for one frame in DWM off for tearing free, first one to present top half, and second one to present bottom half. In this case, the FPS in GPUview actually is double of real FPS. To get real FPS, you also need look the "DX - blt" event, if there are "Present Blt" information in "DX - Blt" event, it indicates the "DX-blt" is for "Present", and then look the Source Rect and Dest Rect information in this event to determine whether the Present is for a full frame or a part of frame.

Answer (score 0):

look for D3D9-Present, and DX-Flip for DX1X. span around for significant amount of time say 1 second. Press Ctrl+E, which will show event viewer, from that, select D3D9-Present or DX-Flip events. Left pane in the event viewer will give you number of these events and you already have the time span you have Zoomed to. I think dividing the number of events by the time would give you average fps for that duration. How gpu view does it, might be running average or instantaneous (1/ deltaT), where deltaT may be time between two events.
Can you try this little math and post some results for reader :)

Comment: By the way here I strictly meant for DX based exclusive full screen games where only 1 process is sending work to gpu.